# No puedo correr mí programa en GO

Tags: vscode, cmd, go

Yo estoy siguiendo este tutorial de Go: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started

pero cuando llego a la parte de correr mi codigo con el comando: go run .

mí CMD me dice: no Go files in C:\Users\saidn\hello.

Osea  no puedo correr my codigo Go en my CMD.

Mí VSCode

```
package main

import (
"fmt"

"rsc.io/quote"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(quote.Go())
}
```

Y aquí mis archivos de Go en Vscode.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una recreación de todos los comandos que puse en el CMD

```
C:\Users\saidn>cd %HOMEPATH%

C:\Users\saidn>mkdir hello
Ya existe el subdirectorio o el archivo hello.

C:\Users\saidn>cd hello

C:\Users\saidn\hello>go mod init example/hello
go: C:\Users\saidn\hello\go.mod already exists

C:\Users\saidn\hello> go run .
no Go files in C:\Users\saidn\hello

C:\Users\saidn\hello>
```

Comment: En la captura se ve que el fichero `hello.go` está dentro de una carpeta llamada `Go`. No se ve que estés dentro de esa carpeta al tratar de ejecutar `go run .`

Comment: En tu vscode ve a `File >  Settings` y   buscar `Code-runner: Executor Map`  y haga clic en `Edit in settings.json`y vea si el **go**  está presente, si no ha instalado el `code runner` en vscode instalar esta herramienta ayudará